# How to make graphql-java-annotations recognize the getters methods as fieldname (without the get)

Tags: java, annotations, graphql

I'm in the process of migrating `graphql-java-annotations` library from version 0.13 to current 6.1 version.

In our application there are many java interfaces which define getter methods for fields.

In version 0.13 we have those getters annotated with `@GraphQLField` and then used with the field name in GraphQL Queries. 
For example:

```
@GraphQLField
String getName();
```

It would be referenced as `name` in GraphQL Queries.

In the current version, the getter method is no longer recognized, and we need to manually annotate the each field with `@GraphQLName` to add  `name` to the GraphQL schema.

In the previous example the following change would work:

```
@GraphQLField
@GraphQLName("name")
String getName();
```

Is there any way to prevent changing all the getters in interfaces by adding the  `@GraphQLName` annotation? Do you know why the getters methods are no longer recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, we were able to solve the problem with the following line:

```
GraphQLAnnotations.getInstance()
    .getObjectHandler()
    .getTypeRetriever()
    .getGraphQLFieldRetriever()
    .setAlwaysPrettify(true);
```